# How to compare two hours and say which one is later or earlier?

Tags: c++, time, compare

How to compare two hours? I tried with the code below but it gives me two times `true`, but it should give `false` and `true`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool earlierEqual(int h1, int m1, int s1, int h2, int m2, int s2)
{
    if(h1 <= h2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(m1 <= m2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(s1 <= s2)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}

bool laterEqual(int h1, int m1, int s1, int h2, int m2, int s2)
{
    if(h1 >= h2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(m1 >= m2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(s1 >= s2)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int h1 = 12, m1 = 4, s1 = 29;
    int h2 = 11, m2 = 12, s2 = 1;

    // false
    cout << earlierEqual(h1, m1, s1, h2, m2, s2) << "\n";
    // true
    cout << laterEqual(h1, m1, s1, h2, m2, s2) << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You code will be easier to maintain in the future if you implement `laterEqual` in terms of `earlierEqual`.  There is no reason to have the full functionality implemented in both of these functions, just have one of them call the other and reverse the order of the arguments.  This is similar to how ordering is handled by containers in the STL by relying (by default at least) only on `std::less` (and not `std::greater`)

Comment: @BrianBrown: In terms of readability and conciseness of  the data represented, I think my solution is the better than the one you have accepted ;-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `else` branch should be activated only if the hours are equal. Otherwise, the comparison of minutes will decide even if the hour `h1` is *greater* than the hour `h2`. You should change your code into the following:

```
bool earlierEqual(int h1, int m1, int s1, int h2, int m2, int s2)
{
    if (h1 < h2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (h1 == h2)
    {
        if (m1 < m2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (m1 == m2)
        {
            if (s1 < s2)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: With your function, for data: `int h1 = 10, m1 = 4, s1 = 29; int h2 = 11, m2 = 12, s2 = 1;` it shows false but should be true

Comment: @BrianBrown: You're right, I haven't been careful enough. Sorry about that, I fixed it.

Comment: thanks :) So laterEqual should look just like this: http://pastie.org/private/huz6oeo6wxorjyjtxmgrhq ?

Answer (score 1):

If hours are equal, you have to check minutes, and if these are equal, you have to check seconds. Only if there is a less condition, you can immediately return true. Same applies to the second function: Only if greater you can do early return.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to convert everything in seconds before doing your comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it. It's more readable and less error-prone. Convert to seconds and then do the comparison.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool earlierEqual(int h1, int m1, int s1, int h2, int m2, int s2)
{
    int totalSeconds1 = getTotalSeconds(h1, m1, s1);
    int totalSeconds2 = getTotalSeconds(h2, m2, s2);

    if(totalSeconds1 <= totalSeconds2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool laterEqual(int h1, int m1, int s1, int h2, int m2, int s2)
{
    int totalSeconds1 = getTotalSeconds(h1, m1, s1);
    int totalSeconds2 = getTotalSeconds(h2, m2, s2);

    if(totalSeconds1 >= totalSeconds2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool getTotalSeconds(int h1, int m1, int s1)
{
   return h1 * 3600 + m1 * 60 + s1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
#include <tuple>
bool earlierEqual(int h1, int m1, int s1, int h2, int m2, int s2) {
  return std::tie(h1, m1, s1) <= std::tie(h2, m2, s2);
}
bool laterEqual(int h1, int m1, int s1, int h2, int m2, int s2) {
  return std::tie(h1, m1, s1) >= std::tie(h2, m2, s2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion : You can represent hours+mins+seconds in a single 32 bit integer.  ( hours is 0-24 - 5 bits , seconds 0-60 :  6 bits  minutes 0-60  : 6 bits)

Once you have  both the numbers in two ints,  you  basically  put the logic in this block ( you would need bitmasks to extract the hour,minute, seconds)

Psedocode below:

```
bool compare(val1,val2) { 

if(h1 < h2) return true; 
if( h1 ==  h2 && m1 < m2 )  return true;
if( h1 == h2 && m1 == m2 && s1 <s2) return true;
return false  ;
}
```